# reference web service WITHOUT Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ruby, web-services

I currently have a project that does not use Visual Studio, we compile with ruby. I want to consume a remote web service, but I can't find anyone that does it through code. I know it's very easy through Visual Studio, but what is the syntax to connect to the web service?

Comment: This is confusing. Why is there a Ruby tag?

Comment: @theTinMan - presumably "we compile with ruby"

Comment: I added the tag because he wants to call a .net service from a Ruby application.  Probably should have added .net too actually...

Comment: sorry guys. It's actually all .NET, but we use rake to compile the application. I'm still new to this method. I've always been a VS person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this at the command line, with [`wsdl.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (web reference), [`wsewsdl3.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx) (WSE3 web reference), or [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) (WCF service reference). This will consume the WSDL/MEX and generate your proxy layer as a C# class file.

Comment: I just realized that this was the right answer. Thanks. I didn't know a whole dll had to be generated.

Comment: @JohnathanKong it doesn't; you just use that C# file in your code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about an asmx web service:

VS creates a local proxy for you to address the web service. Absent of that the easiest way to talk to a web service is by enabling HttpGet/HttpPost in the web.config of the web service - then you can just use standard HTTP requests:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

This way you can call the method `Bar()` on your web service `Foo` by making an HTTP GET request to `http://server/Foo.asmx/Bar`.

Comment: then how do I call the service? I was hoping to make it same as importing a dll, which is how it works on the Visual Studio side.

Comment: @JohnathanKong: In Visual Studio, when you add the reference it does more than just adding a reference.  It generates a bunch of code behind the scenes that wraps the method calls with WebClient to connect.  You need to write code to connect to those HTTP url's and process the data results.

Comment: That's the code I'm looking for. Is there a lot of code generated by Visual Studio? I thought it was like java where I'd use something like CreateService("serviceURL") to create an instance of the service and just use the object returned to call each method.